# Getting org.postgresql.geometric.PGpoint instead of org.postgis.PGgeometry in Hibernate Spatial

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, postgis, hibernate-spatial

I've been struggling with this for a while. Running on Tomcat 7.0.47

Relevant Entity Class snippet:

```
@Column(name = "geopoint", columnDefinition = "org.postgis.Geometry")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
private com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point geopoint;
```

Here are the libraries I'm using:

```
Hibernate Spatial 4.0-M1
postgis-jdbc 2.1.0SVN (used 1.5.3 before, same issue.)
Hibernate 4.2.7
```

Datasource Info

```
Datasource = org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
Driver Class Name = org.postgis.DriverWrapper
JDBC URL Beginning = jdbc:postgresql_postGIS:
```

The DB is PostgreSql 9.3 on Amazon RDS with PostGIS installed. The column geopoint is of type "point". I created this table using PgAdminIII

Hibernate Session Factory props

```
 <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.showsql">true</prop>
```

I've debugged the code to see that the JDBC seems to be returning PGPoint. PGGeometryValueExtractor.toJTS(Object) receives a PGPoint. It seems Hibernate Spatial intends for it to be a org.postgis.Geometry or org.postgis.PGGeometry object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I created a PGpointType that is a custom type in order to convert before to save it on database: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548731/how-to-work-with-pgpoint-for-geolocation-using-postgresql/53754866#53754866

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`point` is a built-in PostgreSQL core type, not a PostGIS type.

I think you want the column type to be `geometry` if you're going to work with PostGIS. Try changing the column type; if you then store PostGIS points in it, it should behave as expected.

Comment: I think I just figured this out... right as I submitted this question I went and reconfigured the column. I'll report back with my findings. thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Yep. This was it. It's always the little things.