# How to work with PGpoint for Geolocation using PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I found a lot of answers that suggest to use spatial data with Hibernate  [spatial data geolocation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial) but I want to know if that is the best because I found that PostgreSQL works with PGpoint for GeoLocation. I implemented but it doesn't work because doesn't save.

> ERROR: column "location" is of type point but expression is of type character varying

I have the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947713/cant-insert-pgpoint-type-with-jpa) but nobody answered him. So let me add other question below if nobody knows about this question.

*As suggestion I'd want to know what is the best way to use Geo data on Spring Boot Context*

Thanks! have a good day.

Comment: All depends on whether you are restricted to Hibernate. I use DataNucleus and it supports PostGIS types with no issue

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to ***save/update/get/*** PGpoint object directly, 
Then you have to create your own user type for supporting PGpoint in order to convert it, before this is saved, UserType is a class of Hibernate which allows to create custom type in order to convert it before to save on database.
Here is code that you need to implement:

**First:** *Need to create a class that implements of UserType*:

```
public class PGPointType implements UserType {
    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[]
                {
                        Types.VARCHAR
                };
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public Class<PGpoint> returnedClass() {
        return PGpoint.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj, Object obj1) {
        return ObjectUtils.equals(obj, obj1);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object obj) {
        return obj.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor sharedSessionContractImplementor, Object o) throws SQLException {
        if (names.length == 1) {
            if (resultSet.wasNull() || resultSet.getObject(names[0]) == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return new PGpoint(resultSet.getObject(names[0]).toString());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement statement, Object value, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor sharedSessionContractImplementor) throws SQLException {
        if (value == null) {
            statement.setNull(index, Types.OTHER);
        } else {
            statement.setObject(index, value, Types.OTHER);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object obj) {
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object obj) {
        return (Serializable) obj;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable serializable, Object obj) {
        return serializable;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object obj, Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        return obj;
    }

}
```

**Second:** *Need to add on entity header @TypeDef annotation, add a name and the PGPointType that you created it and on some field header of type PGpoint, add @Type annotation with the name that you created it*:

```
  @TypeDef(name = "type", typeClass = PGPointType.class)
  @Entity
  public class Entity {

       @Type(type = "type")
       private PGpoint pgPoint;

       // Getters and setters 

  }
```

Kind regards.

Comment: This answer is amazing! I've looked much, and currently it works to save, update and get. thank you!